# Why is it everytime i try too open up PHP script inside my HREF it kills my site and wont run anything after this?

Tags: php, html, href

Im trying to use the following code:

```
<a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>"><?php echo $meta_title; ?></a>
```

It loads an empty navbar but wont load anything under and there are no links.
cheers.

Comment: Post the `echo site_url('admin/dashboard');`  result.

Comment: seems that your php code returns nothing, check the php code and if the php really works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question. Give more details.

What is the result of the following?

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo site_url('admin/dashboard');
    echo $meta_title;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I think its a problem with the site_url function() as im getting this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url() in /var/www/html/trc.better2know.net/application/views/_layout_main.php on line 32

Comment: Yes, you are right. Change code to <a class="brand" href="/admin/dashboard"><?php echo $meta_title; ?></a> and it will be work.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was i hadnt autoloaded the url helper.